# Map index of numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matrix

How should I map indices of a numpy matrix?

For example:

```
mx = np.matrix([[5,6,2],[3,3,7],[0,1,6]]
```

The row/column indices are 0, 1, 2.

So:

```
>>> mx[0,0]
5
```

Let s say I need to map these indices, converting `0, 1, 2` into, e.g. `10, 'A', 'B'` in the way that:

```
mx[10,10] #returns 5
mx[10,'A'] #returns 6 and so on..
```

I can just set a `dict` and use it to access the elements, but I would like to know if it is possible to do something like what I just described.

Comment: What if the input is not a square matrix?

Comment: In my case, there will be only nxn, but if a method exists, it should map row indeces and column indeces I guess. Something like passing two dicts, one for rows and one for columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using [`pandas` dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) with the index and columns using the new mapping for row and col indexing respectively for ease in indexing. It allows us to select a single element or an entire row or column with the familiar `colon` operator.

Consider a generic (non-square 4x3 shaped matrix) -

```
mx = np.matrix([[5,6,2],[3,3,7],[0,1,6],[4,5,2]])
```

Consider the mappings for rows and columns -

```
row_idx = [10, 'A', 'B','C']
col_idx = [10, 'A', 'B']
```

Let's take a look on the workflow with the given sample -

```
# Get data into dataframe with given mappings
In [57]: import pandas as pd

In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame(mx,index=row_idx, columns=col_idx)

# Here's how dataframe data looks like
In [60]: df
Out[60]: 
    10  A  B
10   5  6  2
A    3  3  7
B    0  1  6
C    4  5  2

# Get one scalar element
In [61]: df.loc['C',10]
Out[61]: 4

# Get one entire col
In [63]: df.loc[:,10].values
Out[63]: array([5, 3, 0, 4])

# Get one entire row
In [65]: df.loc['A'].values
Out[65]: array([3, 3, 7])
```

And best of all we are not making any extra copies as the dataframe and its slices are still indexing into the original matrix/array memory space -

```
In [98]: np.shares_memory(mx,df.loc[:,10].values)
Out[98]: True
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'd recommend [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for fast *scalar* access by label. `loc` has bit more overhead, I believe.

Comment: I need to work with numpy matrices because the data, coming from pandas dfs, is just too big to manage. I guess that the easier (smarter?) way is just to build a dict and use it to access the elements. A sistem of mapping indeces like I asked for is used in omx set of matrices, i.e., and I thought that maybe something similar does exist for numpy matrices, but it seems not. Thank for reply, btw.

Comment: @user9187374 Not sure what you mean by `coming from pandas dfs is too big`, because `df` should be of the same shape as `mx` and occupies the same memory space as listed at the end of the post. Could you clarify?

Comment: dataframes we are using are really big, multindex (8+ sometimes) and I switched the calculation to numpy matrices and narrays. Joins and calculation with so big dfs are just a big no.

Comment: @user9187374 I am not talking about those dataframes. I am talking about the ones created with : `df = pd.DataFrame(mx,index=row_idx, columns=col_idx)`. These are virtually same as input `mx.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(((1,2),(3,4),(50,100)))
dt = np.dtype([('ID', np.int32), ('Ring', np.int32)])
B = np.array(list(map(tuple, A)), dtype=dt)
print(B['ID'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` special methods and create a new class as shown.
Store the index map as a dictionary in an instance variable `self.index_map`.

```
import numpy as np

class Matrix(np.matrix):
    def __init__(self, lis):
        self.matrix = np.matrix(lis)
        self.index_map = {}

    def setIndexMap(self, index_map):
        self.index_map = index_map

    def getIndex(self, key):
        if type(key) is slice:
            return key
        elif key not in self.index_map.keys():
            return key
        else:
            return self.index_map[key]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.matrix[self.getIndex(idx[0]), self.getIndex(idx[1])]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        self.matrix[self.getIndex(idx[0]), self.getIndex(idx[1])] = value
```

---

**Usage:**

Creating a matrix.

```
>>> mx = Matrix([[5,6,2],[3,3,7],[0,1,6]])
>>> mx
Matrix([[5, 6, 2],
        [3, 3, 7],
        [0, 1, 6]])
```

Defining the Index Map.

```
>>> mx.setIndexMap({10:0, 'A':1, 'B':2})
```

Different ways to index the matrix.

```
>>> mx[0,0]
5
>>> mx[10,10]
5
>>> mx[10,'A']
6
```

It also handles slicing as shown.

```
>>> mx[1:3, 1:3]
matrix([[3, 7],
        [1, 6]])
```